# Implementing a pipe in C?

Tags: c, process, fork, pipe, dup

I am trying to implement a simple shell. I fork processes this way:

```
void forkProcess(char* cmd[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    char programPath[BUFFERLENGTH] = "/bin/";
    strcat(programPath, cmd[0]);
    int exitStatus;
    pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
    case -1:
        printf("Fork failed; pid == -1\n");
        break;
    case 0:
        execv(programPath, cmd);
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        waitpid(pid, &exitStatus, 0);
        //printf("Exitstatus = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(exitStatus));
        break;
    }
}
```

Now the `cmd` parameter might contain a pipe, e.g.:

`"ls" "-l" "|" "grep" "whatever" "(char*)NULL";`

So how can I implement the pipe functionality? I know there are functions like `pipe()` and `dup()`, but I don't know how to use them in this context.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fully parse your command line before `fork()`ing to start the child.

If a pipe operator is being used, you must set up the pipe before calling `fork()`, so it is inherited.

In general you must also use `close()` and often `dup()` to make the pipe replace the forked process' stdin.

Continue reading up on these functions to "get" the big picture, or get a book which covers Unix I/O.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may use popen().